# Windows Phone developer developing for Browser

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I know this might seem odd for many Silverlight professionals, but alas, thats the case.

I learnt Silverlight just to make app on Windows Phone 7. Hence, for me Silverlight starts and ends with Windows Phone 7.

So, If I have to now design a Silverlight application for a browser, do I have to go back and learn any additional stuff or is the knowledge gained from learning for Windows Phone good enough to dive into creating the browser application.

I do know scope differences like 3.5+ in phone and 4,5 versions of Silverlight in Browser and lack of controls for Windows Phone development.

Also, I come from a development background, not a designing one.

/andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andy,
most of what you have learned while developing from windows phone will be applicable to the desktop. There are some differences and you can get a good understanding of those differences here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426931(v=vs.95).aspx

hth